# in Firefox when selecting text ,they are disappeared.what can we do?

Tags: css, firefox, text, selection, selected

It is better to tell if you select a text in **firefox** this text selected background and color of selected text are white.
What can we do ?

Answer (score 0):

I can use this css for changing selected text to default values

```
::-moz-selection {
background-color: #3390FF;
color: white;}

::selection {
background-color: #3390FF;
color: white;}
```